Is this a bug in the MS Word's document parser?
Environment: MS Office 2021 (local installation, not online subscription) under Windows 11, both fully up-to-date.
I recently posted about what appears to be a bug in the MS Word method Application.CheckGrammar(). There was only one response, a comment that said the correct result was obtained in Word 365. Thus, it appears to be bug in Word 2021. Now it looks like I've found another one. I'd like to know if others can confirm this.
I have the file "test MS Word parsing.docx" open in Word, containing:

This sentence do have one grammar error. What about ALLL caps, words w1th numerals, and words w!th punctuation m#rks? This is another sentence.

And I have the following code:
Public Sub pListSentences()
' Output a list of the paragraphs and sentences in an open document.

Dim oDoct As Document, oPara As Paragraph, oSent As Range, sDocName As String, _
    nCountPara As Long, nCountSent As Long

sDocName = "test MS Word parsing.docx"
Set oDoct = Documents(sDocName)

Debug.Print "Sub pListSentences()" & vbCrLf
Debug.Print "Paragraphs and sentences in document """ & sDocName & """:"

nCountPara = 0
Debug.Print
Debug.Print oDoct.Range.Paragraphs.Count & " paragraphs:"
For Each oPara In oDoct.Range.Paragraphs
    nCountPara = nCountPara + 1
    nCountSent = 0
    Debug.Print nCountPara & ". " & nx_p_sShowChars(oPara.Range.Text)
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "     " & oPara.Range.Sentences.Count & " sentences in paragraph " & nCountPara & ":"
    For Each oSent In oPara.Range.Sentences
        nCountSent = nCountSent + 1
        Debug.Print "     " & nCountSent & ". " & _
                Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(oSent.Text, _
                " ", "\_"), Chr(180), "\-"), vbCr, "\r"), vbLf, "\n"), vbTab, "\t")
      Next oSent
  Next oPara

Set oDoct = Nothing: Set oSent = Nothing

End Sub         ' pListSentences()

When I run that, I get the following output in the Immediate window:
Sub pListSentences()

Paragraphs and sentences in document "test MS Word parsing.docx":

1 paragraphs:
1. This\_sentence\_do\_have\_one\_grammar\_error.\_What\_about\_ALLL\_caps,\_words\_w1th\_numerals,\_and\_words\_w!th\_punctuation\_m#rks?\_This\_is\_another\_sentence.\r

     3 sentences in paragraph 1:
     1. This\_sentence\_do\_have\_one\_grammar\_error.\_
     2. th\_punctuation\_m#rks?\_
     3. This\_is\_another\_sentence.\r

Note that the second sentence, "What about ... m#rks?", appears in full in the printout of the paragraph, but is missing the first part of it in the printout of the sentence, the part from the beginning of the sentence until and including the exclamation mark in "w!th". Thus, it appears that when Word parses the document into sentences, it somehow chokes on an exclamation mark in the middle of a word.
It would be great if others here could try this out in both Word 2021 and Word 365 and report the results you get. Or if you have an explanation for this behavior that means it's not a bug.

@DanielB - Hmm, you're right. VBA is a programming language, so its technology parses code, not a document. But I don't think it's any more correct to say that the parsing is done by the object model or by the API, which is a programming interface. And "sentence splitter" is just another word for parser. I removed "VBA" from the question where it was implying that the parsing is done by VBA and just left it as Word's document parser, which lies somewhere in the hidden technology of Word. -- Now, can you say what happens when you run this in your version of Word?
